# Entity Framework Many-to-Many Insert throws error Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I created a created a code-first model from database, so I have my entities and context all setup.
Here is a diagram of the problematic tables.
[Many to Many relation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Gan.png)
The relation is there to know which Payment is covering which orders, if that makes sense.
I am attempting to add a record to the PaymentSalesOrder by adding an instance of SalesOrder to payment.SalesOrders in EF.
When calling SaveChanges() I get this error:

> ### ErrorCode
>
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PaymentSalesOrder' >when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Here is the code, basically I query the database for the current customer and include his payments and orders.
I assign payment to sales order and change the payment and the salesOrder to reflect their availability.
Finally I add the salesOrder to the payment and call SaveChanges().

I have a customer with one order and one payment in the database so all entities in this code are filled with proper data.

> ### Code

```
Using db As New eRestaurantEF.Context
        If _customer Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim tmpCustomer As eRestaurantEF.Customer
        tmpCustomer = (From tmp In db.Customers.Include("Payments").Include("SalesOrders")
                       Where tmp.customerID = _customer.customerID
                       Select tmp).FirstOrDefault

        For Each paymentRow As eRestaurantEF.Payment In tmpCustomer.Payments
            If paymentRow.PaymentRemainder > 0 Then

                For Each orderRow As eRestaurantEF.SalesOrder In tmpCustomer.SalesOrders
                    db.SalesOrders.Attach(orderRow)
                    db.Entry(orderRow).State = Entity.EntityState.Unchanged
                    If paymentRow.PaymentRemainder > 0 Then

                        If Not orderRow.FullyPaid Then

                            If paymentRow.PaymentRemainder >= orderRow.Remainder Then
                                Dim remainder As Decimal
                                remainder = paymentRow.PaymentRemainder
                                remainder -= orderRow.Remainder

                                paymentRow.PaymentRemainder = remainder
                                orderRow.Remainder = 0
                                orderRow.IsPaid = True
                                orderRow.IsCredit = True
                                orderRow.FullyPaid = True
                                paymentRow.SalesOrders.Add(orderRow)

                            ElseIf paymentRow.PaymentRemainder <= orderRow.Total Then
                                Dim remainder As Decimal
                                remainder = paymentRow.PaymentRemainder
                                remainder -= orderRow.Remainder

                                If remainder = 0 Then
                                    paymentRow.PaymentRemainder = 0
                                    orderRow.Remainder = 0
                                    orderRow.IsPaid = True
                                    orderRow.IsCredit = True
                                    orderRow.FullyPaid = True
                                    paymentRow.SalesOrders.Add(orderRow)
                                    Exit For

                                ElseIf remainder < 0 Then
                                    paymentRow.PaymentRemainder = 0
                                    orderRow.Remainder = Math.Abs(remainder)
                                    orderRow.IsPaid = False
                                    orderRow.IsCredit = True
                                    orderRow.FullyPaid = False
                                    orderRow.Payments.Add(paymentRow)
                                    Exit For

                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next 'OrdersList
            End If
        Next 'PaymentsList

        db.SaveChanges()
    End Using
```

here is the Fluent Api for the relation table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(Of Payment)() _
    .HasMany(Function(e) e.SalesOrders) _
    .WithMany(Function(e) e.Payments) _
    .Map(Function(m) m.ToTable("PaymentSalesOrder").MapLeftKey("Payment_ID").MapRightKey("SalesOrder_No"))
```

Both FKs at the PaymentSalesOrder table are part of a composite key created at the database to insure that there are no duplicate rows.
I even tried removing the key and changing it to a unique index but the problem persisted.
Here is the table script from Sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PaymentSalesOrder](
    [Payment_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, <---- Here is the culprit remove the identity from this column
    [SalesOrder_No] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PaymentSalesOrder] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Payment_ID] ASC,
    [SalesOrder_No] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentSalesOrder]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PaymentSalesOrder_Payment] FOREIGN KEY([Payment_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Payment] ([PaymentID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentSalesOrder] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PaymentSalesOrder_Payment]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentSalesOrder]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PaymentSalesOrder_SalesOrder] FOREIGN KEY([SalesOrder_No])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SalesOrder] ([SalesOrderNo])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentSalesOrder] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PaymentSalesOrder_SalesOrder]
GO
```

My apologies for the long post but this is really maddening and I can't see where the problem is.
I am considering removing the many-to-many relation alltogether, but giving up without knowing the cause is not easy for me, what if I come across it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly states that You are trying to insert a value in the `IDENTITY` Column but you cannot insert value to an `IDENTITY` Column which in your case is `Payment_ID` of `PaymentSalesOrder` table. `IDENTITY` Column autogenerates its value when you insert a new row by incrementing by `INCREMENT` value provided, in your case is `1`. What I mean to say is whenever you insert a new row the value of `Payment_ID` will insert automatically starting from `1` and will keep incrementing by 1 for each new row.

You can get more informatin on IDENTITY [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

I hope now you are clear

Comment: Thanks @jonju, The answer was right in front of my face all the time and I couldn't see it. I just removed the Identity from the table. Now I have to write a script to change this in the production database. Thanks again